# Safe Transaction Service API endpoint for Base Goerli testnet

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I was using the Safe Transaction Service API to interact with my Safe for creating transactions, but I am unable to find the url to connect to the transaction service on the Base Goerli testnet.

The documentation provides a link to the service API for safes deployed on Ethereum mainnet and eth Goerli testnet though, but I am looking for base testnet urls.